# error '(_, _) -> Void' is not convertible to 'HealthManager' when authorize to HealthKit

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, healthkit

Here is HealthManager Class and a function authorizeHealthKit in it. All of that is in HealthManager.swift file.

```
class HealthManager {
  func authorizeHealthKit(completion: ((success:Bool, error:NSError!) -> Void)!)
  {
    // 1. Set the types you want to read from HK Store
    let healthKitTypesToRead : Set = [
      HKObjectType.characteristicTypeForIdentifier(HKCharacteristicTypeIdentifierDateOfBirth)!,
      HKObjectType.characteristicTypeForIdentifier(HKCharacteristicTypeIdentifierBloodType)!,
      HKObjectType.characteristicTypeForIdentifier(HKCharacteristicTypeIdentifierBiologicalSex)!,
      HKObjectType.quantityTypeForIdentifier(HKQuantityTypeIdentifierBodyMass)!,
      HKObjectType.quantityTypeForIdentifier(HKQuantityTypeIdentifierHeight)!,
      HKObjectType.workoutType()
    ]

// 2. Set the types you want to write to HK Store
let healthKitTypesToWrite : Set = [
  HKObjectType.quantityTypeForIdentifier(HKQuantityTypeIdentifierBodyMassIndex)!,
  HKObjectType.quantityTypeForIdentifier(HKQuantityTypeIdentifierActiveEnergyBurned)!,
  HKObjectType.quantityTypeForIdentifier(HKQuantityTypeIdentifierDistanceWalkingRunning)!,
  HKQuantityType.workoutType()
]

// 3. If the store is not available (for instance, iPad) return an error and don't go on.
if !HKHealthStore.isHealthDataAvailable()
{
  let error = NSError(domain: "Ira.HKTutorial", code: 2, userInfo: [NSLocalizedDescriptionKey:"HealthKit is not available in this Device"])
  if( completion != nil )
  {
    completion(success:false, error:error)
  }
  return;
}

    // 4.  Request HealthKit authorization
    healthKitStore.requestAuthorizationToShareTypes(healthKitTypesToWrite, readTypes: healthKitTypesToRead) { (success, error) -> Void in

      if( completion != nil )
      {
        completion(success:success,error:error)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The problem is when I'm trying to invoke the method authorizeHealthKit() in ViewController.swift:

```
  func authorizeHealthKit()
  {
    HealthManager.authorizeHealthKit {(authorized, error) -> Void in//here is an error '(_, _) -> Void' is not convertible to 'HealthManager'
      if authorized {
        println("HealthKit authorization received.")
      }
      else
      {
        println("HealthKit authorization denied!")
        if error != nil {
          println("\(error)")
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: you are not calling the function on an instance but on the class itself. Consequently, shouldn't it be `class func authorizeHealthKit()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling an *instance* method on a *class*. To call an instance method, you have to create an instance first, e.g.

```
let manager = HealthManager()
manager.authorizeHealthKit { ... }
```

you could also make the method a *class* method:

```
class func authorizeHealthKit(...)
```